# Rx Timeout Operator

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I want to emmit one item after x seconds if no items have been emited. I was trying to use the timeout operator. The problem is that timeout operator requires at least one item to be executed previously to start the countdown. From the documentation:

*"If the next item isn't emitted within the specified timeout duration starting from its predecessor, the resulting Observable begins instead to mirror a fallback Observable."*

That is not the behaviour I'm looking for. When I subscribe to my observable, I want to emit a particular item if a particular period of time elapses without any emitted items previously.

Example:

```
 getUserLocationFromGPS() //Sometimes I dont receive user location
.timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just(getDefaultLocation())
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: maybe just start with getDefaultLocation()?

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I don't want to emit the default location at first, it is only the fallback case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final Observable data = yourApi.getData().take(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
final Observable fallback = Observable.just("Fallback");

Observable.concat(data, fallback).firstOrError()
            .subscribe(
                    System.out::println
            );
```

1. If `yourApi.getData()` does not emit anything then you will receive data from your fallback observable.
2. If `yourApi.getData()` timeouts then you will receive data from your fallback observable.
3. If `yourApi.getData()` emits normally then you will receive data from it.

Comment: Hi, I am already using that parameter. Mi problem is not that. You are always emitting one item, "Hello". In my case, I could have no items emitted previously, so the timeout operator does not start the countdown.

Comment: @VictorManuelPinedaMurcia Can you mark the answer as accepted for clarity purpose then? Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use java-rx specifically, but here is an idea:

```
getUserLocationFromGPS()
.buffer(5 sec, 1 item) //not sure how to do this in rx-java
.map(x => { // this is select in .net
    if(x.IsEmpty)
      return getDefautLocation();
    else
      return x[0];
    }).Subscribe(...)
```

[buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) will get you list of items every 5sec. You can specify it to return after only 1 item was emited by getUserLocationFromGPS()

[map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) will check if the list is empty (no item was emited) and return proper value

Comment: I'm afraid it not working for me. If getUserLocationFromGPS() doesn't emit an item, buffer not emit a empty list after 5 secs. Map operator it not executed in that case. I will stick to Benjamin solution. Thanks you very much!